# How to log when windows service is being stopped by server restart c#

Tags: c#, .net, crash, windows-services, topshelf

I want to handle when windows service is killed by task manager or by system restart.

I tried using below handler inside Timer_Elapsed method of the service timer

```
  public void Start()
    {
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += CurrentDomain_UnhandledException;
        _myTimer= new Timer(10000);
        _myTimer.Elapsed += OnElapsed;
        _myTimer.AutoReset = false;
        _myTimer.Start();
    }

  private void OnElapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
     {
                try
                {
                   _myTimer.Stop();
                   //Work
                }
                finally
                {
                    _myTimer.Start();
                }
     }
```

and even I have placed the same into Main() method of the console as I am using Topshelf for windows service.

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += CurrentDomain_UnhandledException;
        var exitCode = HostFactory.Run(hostConfigurator =>
        {
            hostConfigurator.Service<MyService>(serviceConfigurator =>
            {
                serviceConfigurator.ConstructUsing(() => new MyService());
                serviceConfigurator.WhenStarted(MyService => MyService.Start());
                serviceConfigurator.WhenStopped(MyService=> MyService.Stop());
            });

            hostConfigurator.RunAsLocalSystem();

            hostConfigurator.SetDisplayName("MyService");
            hostConfigurator.SetDescription("MyService");
            hostConfigurator.SetServiceName("MyService");
            hostConfigurator.UseLog4Net();
        });
}


private static void CurrentDomain_UnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
        {
            File.AppendAllText(@"C:\Crash.txt", "Main Termination");
        }
```

In either scenario the handler is not getting called when I kill the windows service process from task manager or system restart. Even TopShelf is not logging "UnhandledServiceException" exit code.

I have searched Google for all possible ways but no luck. Could any one please help me in this.

Thanks

Comment: If you just want to log it, is the windows event log not enough? It logs service shut downs etc already, or can be turned on.

Comment: That's not my expectation @Ryios. I have to update inprogress work status in the database so that I can resume it once the service is restarted

Comment: I don't think there is a event/handler allowing you to detect when the process is being killed via task manager. There is one though when system restart is requested ( Look at docs for `SystemEvents.SessionEnding` ).

However, if I were you I would log inprogress work status in a tmp log file as I go. So that if process is killed for any reason and then resumed you can read this file and know what to do next.

Comment: MSDN says "Console applications do not raise the SessionEnding event". This event is only raised if the message pump is running. In a Windows service, unless a hidden form is used or the message pump has been started manually, this event will not be raised. For a code example that shows how to handle system events by using a hidden form in a Windows service, see the SystemEvents class. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.systemevents.sessionending%28v=vs.110%29.aspx